# Can I change a contribution's values for Financial Type and Campaign directly in SQL without danger?

Tags: civicontribute, mysql, civicampaign, sql, financial-types

When using "Import Contributions > Update Existing Contributions" I can import a Financial Type using the full name of an existing (and active) Financial Type. However, if I try to use the full name of an existing (and active) campaign it does not seem to work consistently.

**EDIT** 
I notice that in the database the `civicrm_contribution` table has fields for `financial_type_id` and `campaign_id` -- **is there any danger in using some SQL directly to populate these values?** (ie. can anyone verify that if I set those IDs correctly in this table, it won't conflict with anything else)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the in core CiviAccounts bits - then changing the financial_type_id is ok. We do lots of retyping (update more specific financial_type_ids ad-hoc) - on projects where we do our own Accounting integration i.e. bypassing the core CiviAccounts.

PS - forgot to note that updating campaign_id should be safe

Comment: And if there is use (or plan to use) CiviAccounts in the future -- are there other tables that can be updated in a similar way, or do you recommend not touching the tables directly in that case?

Comment: I'd turn it around: only if/when you're going to using CiviAccounts (Financial tables) in future - then write a script that will update/insert all financial bits in all tables in involved - and I urge you to run some consistency/checks as part of that. Especially, if your org has subsequent recurring contributions.